# DDD constrained by ActiveObjects framework

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

My team decided to try DDD approach in new app we're developing now.
One of the obstacles that we face is our platform - we are forced to use ActiveObjects ORM framework (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started+with+Active+Objects).

Given that DDD is huge topic by itself, existence of such a constraint makes things more complex. The main problem is propagation of changes of Domain Model entity attributes to the persistence storage via ActiveObjects. Are there any good solutions we can consider?

Answer (score 0):

ORM is a persistence detail i.e totally unrelated to the Domain (different layers). DDD is not a huge topic. It's a simple mindset, tricky to understand and very skill dependent to implement (it's not a "how to" methodology).

DDD uses Repositories for everything persistence related. The Domain only sees the repositories (abstractions only), never the db, orm etc. The ORM is used by the repository. A properly encapsulated domain object might not be easily mappable to an ORM and you'll need different approaches for those cases (the memento pattern is a clean but expensive - boring - to maintain solution). But the essence is that Domain doesn't know about ORM and the Repository is responsible for persisting/retrieving domain objects (using the ORM).

You should also employ CQRS, you don't want your business objects designed for UI or reporting queries.